# Calling a tabulator table function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tabulator

I am using Tabulator under React, with the react-tabulator module.

I am missing something very basic, likely due to my new knowledge of React. Implementing this module, I know how to connect a tabulator callback to a javascript function. But I don't know how to call a tabulator method. For instance:

```
  const options = {
    height: '100%',
    ajaxURL: 'http://example.com',
    ajaxProgressiveLoad: 'scroll',
    ajaxError: (error) => {
      console.log('ajaxError ', error);
    },
  };

...

      <ReactTabulator
        columns={columns}
        layout="fitColumns"
        data={[]}
        options={options}
      />
```

Here the ajaxError callback is passed to ReactTabulator, and called when appropriate.

Now, the tabulator module has lots of methods, for instance setData. Outside of React, this would be used as follows:

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    ajaxURL:"http://www.getmydata.com/now", //ajax URL
});

...

table.setData("http://www.getmydata.com/now");
```

How do I translate this into the React world (in a hook environment), since I don't have direct access to the equivalent of a 'table' object? Do I need to get to my tabulator object by using getElementById or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the solution is to use a ref as described here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
, in the section:

> Refs and Function Components
>
> By default, you may not use the ref attribute on function components because they don’t have instances:
>
> ...
>
> You can, however, use the ref attribute inside a function component as long as you refer to a DOM element or a class component:

Using this approach I am able to access my tabulator setData method.

```
const tableDisplay = (props) => {
  const tableRef = createRef();

  // I can now use setData in various effects:
  // if ((tableRef.current) && (tableRef.current.table)) {
  //    tableRef.current.table.setData();

  return (
      <ReactTabulator
        ref={tableRef}
        columns={columns}
        layout="fitColumns"
        data={[]}
        options={options}
      />
  );
};
```

This works just fine, I am just not sure this is the "clean" way to go about it?

Comment: That is correct, simply create a ref to reference ReactTabulator instance. Using this ref, we can access tabulator methods and properties available. That is the way I have been using in my react app so far.

Comment: Which version is it? For 5.4, it is not working. Returning null instead of methods.

Comment: I am using react-tabulator 0.15.0, which uses tabulator-tables 4.9.3.

Answer (score -1):

You need to fetch the api from useEffect and useState its result. Heres an example

```
import React,{ useState, useEffect }from "react"
import { ReactTabulator } from "react-tabulator"

const Dashboard = props => {
    const [data,setData] = useState([])

    const getData = async () => {
        const result = await fetch("http://www.getmydata.com/now") // this is where you call the api and get its result
        setState(result.data) // this is where you set the result to your state
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
      getData()
    },[])

    const columns=[
        {
            title:"name",
            field:"name",
        },
        {
            title:"Number of Request"
            field:"noOfRequest",
        }
    ]

    return (
        <ReactTabulator
        columns={columns}
        layout="fitColumns"
        data={data} // here is the state of the table
        options={options}
        />
    )

}

export default Dashboard
```

This is how you get data from an api in React.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am however more after how to get to that ReactTabulator setData method (for instance when I want to reload some remote data, or also want to take advantage of progressive loading / scrolling). So I'm really trying to figure out what is the "clean" way of calling that method, not so much how to pass data to the object?

Comment: This is not what OP asked for. He was looking for a way to get access to Tabulator methods. The OP has figured out himself the solution for his problem as stated in his answer below which I support.